# Behavior of $ f(x) $ near $ x_{0} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ g'(x) = f(x) $ be an autonomous $ 1 $st order DE such that $ f(x_{0}) = 0. $ What can you say about solutions of $ g(x) $ near $ x_{0} $ if

a) $ f'(x_{0}) = 0? $ For this one I think that since $ x_{0} $ is either a stable, unstable, or semistable of $ f(x), $ it is also either a stable, unstable, or semistable of $ f'(x_{0}). $ Is there any example to illustrate this? I cannot find an $ f(x) $ such that $ f(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0}) = 0. $

b) $ f'(x_{0}) = 0 $ but $ f''(x_{0}) \ne 0? $

c) $ f'(x_{0}) = f''(x_{0}) = 0 $ but $ f'''(x_{0}) \ne 0? $

Comment: All three of "stable", "unstable", and "semistable" are adjectives that should be modifying a noun.  Your noun is missing both times.

Comment: Do you know that $x_0$ is an ordinary point for your DE?

Comment: Since $f(x) = (x-x_0)^2$ is the canonical example of a function that satisfies $f(x_0) = f'(x_0) = 0$ without being the zero function, are you sure an example of "$f(x_0) - f'(x_0) = 0$" is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You realize (?) you can get any set of $f(x_0), f'(x_0), f''(x_0), ...$ by writing down the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x_0$ and plugging in the values you want for the various derivatives (and either setting the unspecified ones to $0$ or giving them whatever random values you want as long as the result is either a polynomial or converges on some neighborhood of $x_0$.).  This gives you infinitely many examples of functions satisfying your various conditions that are all polynomials and a way to construct other non-polynomial examples.  For example, $f$,$f'$,$f''$, ..., $f^{(5)}$ all zero at $x_0$ and $f^{(7)}(x_0) = 23$:  First write out the expansion, then plug in the constraints: 
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{1}{2!}f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2 + \cdots  \\
 &= 0 + 0(x-x_0) + 0(x-x_0)^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{6!}f^{(6)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^6 +  \\
    &\qquad + \frac{1}{7!}\cdot 23 \cdot (x-x_0)^7 + \frac{1}{8!}f^{(8)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^8 + \cdots  \\
 &= \frac{1}{6!}f^{(6)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^6 + \frac{23}{7!} (x-x_0)^7 + \frac{1}{8!}f^{(8)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^8 + \cdots  \text{.}
\end{align}
Then we are free to set the unspecified derivatives however we like.  I like $\pi$ for the sixth derivative and (for a polynomial) setting the eighth and all higher derivatives to zero or (for a non-polynomial) copying the tail of the exponential function (expanded at $0$), by setting the eighth and higher derivatives to $1$.